# prevent autovacuum on specific table postgres 9.6

Tags: postgres-9.6

I tried to execute the query
ALTER TABLE [table]  SET (autovacuum_enabled = false, toast.autovacuum_enabled = false);

The autovacuum is still running on the table that I want to disable the autovacuum for.

Any suggestions ?